# Specify data frame programmatically using paste() and replace value at index

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe `x1`:

```
x1 <- data.frame(Var1 = 1, Var2 = 2, Var3 = 3)
```

To edit a cell, say row 1 of `Var1` I would do:

```
> x1 <- data.frame(Var1 = 1, Var2 = 2, Var3 = 3)
> x1
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    2    3
> x1[1,1] <- 10
> x1
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1   10    2    3
```

Now my question is, how to I obtain the same result using paste() to specify the data frame like this: `paste0("x", 1)`.

I have tried the following:

`paste0("x", 1)[1,1] <- 10 #obviously won't work`

Using `assign()`: `assign(paste0("x", 1)[1,1], 10)`

Using `get()`: `get(paste0("x", 1))[1,1] <- 10`

Using `eval()`: `eval(parse(paste0("x", 1)))[1,1] <- 10`

All resolve in the same error:

> target of assignment expands to non-language object.

How will I be able to solve this without any workarounds?

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, the following works:

```
y <- get(paste0("x", 1))
y[1,1] <- 10
assign(paste0("x", 1), y)
```

But I was wondering if there is a direct way of doing this, instead of this workaround.

Comment: you could do `y <- get(paste0("x", 1))` and then do `y[1, 1] <- 10` ?

Comment: @RonakShah noticed that. But was wondering if there is a direct way of doing this. I will edit my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `assign` in this way :

```
assign(paste0("x", 1), `[<-` (x1, 1, 1, 10))

x1
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1   10    2    3
```

Or

```
assign(paste0("x", 1), `[<-` (get(paste0("x",1)), 1, 1, 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functional version of `[<-.data.frame`:

```
`[<-.data.frame`(get(paste0("x", 1)), 1, 1, 10)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1   10    2    3
```

Or use the generic replacement function and rely on correct dispatching

```
`[<-`(get(paste0("x", 1)), 1, 1, 10)
```

---

That said, instead of having (many) data frames floating around in your workspace, it may be better to store them in a (named) list.